# How to transform a repeating list into a list with a count?

Tags: vb.net, list, count

I have a list(Of transaction) :

```
Type | State  
----------------
boat | buy
boat | buy
boat | sell
car  | sell
car  | sell
car  | sell
plane| buy
```

How can I transform it to a list(Of transactionShortened) :

```
Type | State | Quantity  
-----------------------
boat | buy   | 2
boat | sell  | 1
car  | sell  | 3
plane| buy|  | 1
```

Elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ and [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx):

```
Dim transactionGroups =
        From t In transactions
        Group t By Key = New With {
            .Type = t.Type,
            .State = t.State
        } Into Group
        Select New With {
            .Type = Key.Type,
            .State = Key.State,
            .Quantity = Group.Count()
        }

For Each tGroup In transactionGroups
    Dim type = tGroup.Type
    Dim state = tGroup.State
    Dim quantity = tGroup.Quantity  
Next
```

Comment: Since my type and state are object, I had to change this solution a bit, mainly : `Group t By Key = String.Format("{0}{1}", t.type.Id.ToString(), t.statut.Id.ToString()) Into Group` and `With {.type = Group.First().type.Id, .statut = Group.First.statut.Id, .quantite = Group.Count()}`